# ActivityTestRule.getActivity returns null in Before method

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, kotlin

I need to empty my user's data before each test

```
// Kotlin code
fun getActivity() = activityRule.getActivity()

Before
fun setUp() {
    cleanUp(getActivity())
}
```

I need to get a Context in order to do so, but in setUp, activityRule.getActivity() returns null.

I also tried:

```
Before
fun setUp() {
    val i = Intent()
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    activityRule.lauchActivity(i)
    cleanUp(getActivity())
}
```

I got an activity, but cleanUp works only half of the time (I believe some race condition apply here)

I want to avoid to cleanUp in an After function in order to see manually my app state if needed.

Is there anyway to get a context in a Before function?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the production app context from `InstrumentationRegistry` like so:
`InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`

Keep in mind that: `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` is the context of your test apk.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment of writing, `InstrumentationRegistry` is deprecated.
I use `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Application>()` from `androidx.test` library instead.

The dependency is: `androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1"`

Comment: androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry is deprecated. using androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.